# Jenkins: Escaping % in parameterized jobs

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to run this command from shell as a build step on a Windows machine:

> for /R . %f in (*.bin) do copy "%f" "..\Release\"

After struggling for a while figuring out why it doesn't work, I noticed this is a parameterized build and that parameters are of the form %var%. I assume is trying to replace % with an empty value since there's nothing defined. It is translated to on the first loop:

> for /R . f" "..\Release\Newer\"

I guess I could define a parameter like %f% = %f and it might do the trick, but seems unnecessary.

Comment: FYI, my proposed fix did work, still consider it a workaround for a valid issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume you are using Windows environment (you should really specify), and as such it is not a "shell" build step, but "Execute Windows Batch Command" build step (if it's not, you need to use "Execute Windows Batch Command" build step)

Next, it's a peculiarity of Windows Batch, that when you run it from command line, you can use a single `%` in the `FOR` statement, however when you run it from a batch file (and the batch build step **is** a temporary batch file), you need to use `%%`. *Note, this only applies to the `FOR` statement as it uses a special syntax for the variables.*

So change your line to:

`for /R . %%f in (*.bin) do copy "%%f" "..\Release\"`